# Custom user field value subtracted from woocommerce subtotal

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have added a custom user field which shows as expected

```
add_action( 'show_user_profile', 'extra_user_profile_fields' );
add_action( 'edit_user_profile', 'extra_user_profile_fields' );

function extra_user_profile_fields( $user ) { ?>
    <h3 style="padding-top:20px"><?php _e("Account Credit", "blank"); ?></h3>

    <table class="form-table">
    <tr>
        <th><label for="credit_amount"><?php _e("Credit Amount (£)"); ?></label></th>
        <td>
            <input type="text" name="credit_amount" id="credit_amount" value="<?php echo esc_attr( get_the_author_meta( 'credit_amount', $user->ID ) ); ?>" class="regular-text" /><br />
            <span class="description"><?php _e("Customer shop credit balance."); ?></span>
        </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
<?php }

add_action( 'personal_options_update', 'save_extra_user_profile_fields' );
add_action( 'edit_user_profile_update', 'save_extra_user_profile_fields' );

function save_extra_user_profile_fields( $user_id ) {
    if ( empty( $_POST['_wpnonce'] ) || ! wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['_wpnonce'], 'update-user_' . $user_id ) ) {
        return;
    }
    
    if ( !current_user_can( 'edit_user', $user_id ) ) { 
        return false; 
    }
    update_user_meta( $user_id, 'credit_amount', $_POST['credit_amount'] );
}
```

[image]

I have then added more custom code to get the value of the credit amount for the current user and apply this to the coupon total / label, after a sucessfull order has been placed it then sets the credit amount to zero (0).

```
function woocommerce_filter_checkout_for_coupons( $subtotal, $compound, $cart ) {     

        // Your logic to get store credit value for a user will go here
        $store_credit = get_user_meta(get_current_user_id(), 'credit_amount', true );
            
        if($store_credit > 0){

            $coupon_name = 'store-credit';
            $coupon = array($coupon_name => $store_credit);

            $cart->applied_coupons = array($coupon_name);
            $cart->set_discount_total($store_credit);
            $cart->set_total( $cart->get_subtotal() - $store_credit);
            $cart->coupon_discount_totals = $coupon;
        }
    
    

    return $subtotal; 
}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_subtotal', 'woocommerce_filter_checkout_for_coupons', 10, 3 );

add_action( 'woocommerce_thankyou', 'checkout_save_user_meta' );
 
function checkout_save_user_meta( $order_id ) {
   $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );
   $user_id = $order->get_user_id(); 
   update_user_meta( $user_id, 'credit_amount', 0 );

}
```

When going to the basket / checkout page it displays the label Coupon: store-credit and the value is equal to the value in the user field. After making the purchase, the users credit is set back to zero (0).

[image]

However issues I am facing:

1. The VAT amount and grand total is incorrect , £109.20 original amount, minus £50.00 in this case = £59.20, 20% VAT = £11.84 , the total should be £71.04 - it should not charge VAT amount on £109.20 when the new subtotal is £59.20
2. The order success / thank you page shows no discount / coupon and the vat and total is incorrect.
3. Their is no discount / coupon showing, the vat and total is incorrect on the order page (admin side) and on the customer confirmation & admin order notification emails.
4. How can I also check if a user's credit amount was used for an order then deduct it from their meta data, rather than just having it reset the users credit_amount to zero everytime even when/if they may not have any credit available and used any.
5. Allow user credit to be used in conjuction with actual back-end created coupon codes /